# What can Hasselblad Phocus do with JPEGs?

Tags: photo-management, hasselblad

I've started using Hasselblad Phocus (3.3.6) to organise and clean up my photo collection, and having shot primarily in JPEG, am missing the White Balance and Noise Filter menu items, amongst others. I can't find anything in the documentation - is it really the case that these menu items are only active for RAW images?

Comment: The RAW files have way more information on them than the JPEG, it is reasonable that some filters would operate on that information, so they would not be available for jpegs.  The same is true in photoshop as well, Canon's DPP, etc..

Comment: @FábioDias, why LR have all the sliders for `JPEG`? It's not only about format, it's about manufacturer decision

Comment: @RomeoNinov Because LR decided that they would use fancy algorithms to do at least a bit of color correction - which in reality is not as simple on a JPEG as it is on a RAW, as you have to interpolate the missing information. I would guess that most software developers think that their RAW workflow is more important than their JPEG workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take @Romeo Ninov's comment as my answer: manufacturer decision. I was hoping someone would tell me how to whitebalance my JPEGs in Phocus, but it seems that this is indeed not possible due to it not being desired by Hasselblad.

Answer (score 2):

[From the manual, page 10](http://static.hasselblad.com/2014/12/Phocus_User-Manual_Eng_v20.pdf#page=10):

> Phocus primarily fully supports Hasselblad 3FR and 3F files with more limited 
>   support for other format files.

This is true for most RAW converters. Some do try to offer some/all options to JPEG as well, but since they lack the information that RAW files still have, it is a different algorithm that has to interpolate the missing information, while RAW white balance correction is relatively easy. My personal guess is that most developers think that RAW is the format that people use to edit their picture.